# Executing java program with ./programName

Tags: java, linux

I'm doing a coding challenge and have all the logic and code done, but the instructions say they want to be able to execute the program with the following format:

./programName arg1 arg2 etc...

Being that I've mostly coded in Windows, I'm not sure how this is done. I created an executable jar, but that doesn't seem to conform to how they want to run the program. It seems like I can make a .sh file to run the program like .sh ./programName arg1 arg2 etc..., but even then I have the .sh in front.

Comment: Answered here: http://superuser.com/q/912955

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!